# Is there any way to Install packages on python for the Casio Cg50 Calculator?

Tags: python, pip, calculator, python-packaging, micropython

I've recently been looking into emulators (and purchase) of a Casio CG50 Calculator. It has an option to run python, and I think runs on micropython. It obviously doesn't have pip, so I was wondering if there was any way to import external modules and packages, maybe by installing the git repo for a package? Thanks.

[Download link for Casio Cg50 Emulator](https://education.casio.co.uk/cg50-emulator-request)

Answer (score 1):

When you need to manually install a library, you can just copy the file from the Repo to your project.